# Trouble reusing the same Http after passing it from a sub to a function

Tags: vba, function, web-scraping, queryselector

I've written a script using xhr to parse the link of the first post from this [website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping) and then passed the `link` and the `http` to a function to fetch the title from it's inner page. ***It's important that I pass both the `link` and the `http` to the function in order to reuse the same http that I have used in the first place***.

My script appears to be working in the right way but I'm not sure I did the whole thing in the right way. The reason for my confusion is that I get the result when I use like `getHTTP(ByVal Http, ByVal link) As Variant`. I even get the result when I go for `getHTTP(ByVal Http, ByVal link) As String` or `getHTTP(ByVal Http, ByVal link)`. Moreover, I didn't explicitly define `link as String` or `Http as XMLHTTP60` within function parameters.

I've tried with (working flawlessly):

```
Function getHTTP(ByVal Http, ByVal link) As Variant
    Dim Html As New HTMLDocument, oTitle$
    
    With Http
        .Open "GET", link, False
        .send
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        oTitle = Html.querySelector("h1[itemprop='name'] > a").innerText
        getHTTP = oTitle
    End With
End Function

Sub GetInfo()
    Const base$ = "https://stackoverflow.com"
    Const Url$ = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping"
    Dim Http As New XMLHTTP60, Html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim firstLink$, postTitle$

    With Http
        .Open "GET", Url, False
        .send
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        firstLink = base & Replace(Html.querySelector(".summary .question-hyperlink").getAttribute("href"), "about:", "")
        postTitle = getHTTP(Http, firstLink)
        MsgBox postTitle
    End With
End Sub
```

> What is the right way to pass http between sub and function in order to reuse the same http?

Comment: This forum is for code which has logic errors.  If your code is working fine, and you just want to improve it, you should post on code review instead.

Comment: Unless there's a reason not to be explicit, then I recommend _being_ explicit.  So in this case, `getHTTP(ByVal Http As XMLHTTP60, ByVal link As String) As String`.  All other examples you provided use Variants either implicitly or explicitly which as you saw work fine, too.

Comment: There's no reason to pass the http object - it uneccessarily complicates your code for no real gain: the overhead of spinning up another object is negligible.

Comment: Yes, it does @Tim Williams. The code I've pasted above is merely an example. Passing http to a function matters because I reused that http to parse content from different depth from a site after logging in.

Comment: Even when the code is working, I might have done most of it in a wrong manner and that is what my question is about @freeflow.

Comment: Might have been useful to be a bit more explicit about that requirement

Comment: Could you please add the code where `getHTTP` and `GetInfo` are called from.

Comment: @omegastripes - `getHTTP` is called from `GetInfo` (which I'd assume is called directly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might be appropriate:

```
Sub GetInfo()

    Const base As String = "https://stackoverflow.com"
    Const url As String = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping"
    Dim Html As HTMLDocument
    Dim firstLink As String, postTitle As String

    firstLink = base & Replace(GetPage(url).querySelector(".summary .question-hyperlink") _
                .getAttribute("href"), "about:", "")
    Debug.Print firstLink

    postTitle = GetPage(firstLink).querySelector("h1[itemprop='name'] > a").innerText
    Debug.Print postTitle

End Sub

Function GetPage(url As String) As HTMLDocument
    Dim Html As HTMLDocument
    Static Http As XMLHTTP60

    If Http Is Nothing Then
        Set Http = New XMLHTTP60
        'log in here
    End If

    With Http
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .send
        If .Status = 200 Then
            Set Html = New HTMLDocument
            Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        Else
            Debug.Print .Status
            'warn user
        End If
    End With
    Set GetPage = Html
End Function
```

Above all assumes the "happy path" so probably would benefit from some exception handling...

Comment: Hi Tim, you are almost there. The only thing that is yet to be implemented is http in both sub and function. You might have noticed that I did half of the scraping in sub and the rest of it in a function, so passing http matters. In fact, I wanna do the scraping in both places individually, so it is necessary for the same http to exist in both the places. Thanks.

Comment: That was the point of centralizing the fetch in a single location: you cannot use the HTTP in two locations at exactly the same time (since it cannot make concurrent connections), so why not just keep it in one place?  All you need in any other methods is a html document - there's no need to manage the fetch in those methods.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following should do what you wanna achieve:

```
Function getHTTP(ByVal Http, link) As String
    With Http
        .Open "GET", link, False
        .send
        getHTTP = .responseText
    End With
End Function

Sub GetInfo()
    Const base$ = "https://stackoverflow.com"
    Const Url$ = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping"
    Dim Http As Object, Html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim firstLink$
    
    Set Http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    Html.body.innerHTML = getHTTP(Http, Url)
    firstLink = base & Replace(Html.querySelector(".summary .question-hyperlink").getAttribute("href"), "about:", "")
    
    Html.body.innerHTML = getHTTP(Http, firstLink)
    MsgBox Html.querySelector("h1[itemprop='name'] > a").innerText
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your issue correctly and you need changes made to the http instance in the function to be passed to your calling sub then passing http **ByRef** will be enough. Passing the variable ByRef passes changes made to the http instance in the function to the sub for use outside of the function. So changes made to http in the function will be passed to the sub and will not be lost. You will be using the same instance of the http object in both places. Passing http ByVal won't pass the changes made to http in the function to the sub. Change your function parameters declaration as follows.

```
    Function getHTTP(ByRef Http, ByVal link) As Variant
```